# Delphi, drawing a mouse selection rectangle in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, mouse, firemonkey

I need to do a simple thing using Delphi FMX that can be done easily by VCl: a rectangle on the control canvas, which bottom right point is following the mouse (Selection rectangle). I wrote a code like that:

> ```
> interface 
> type
>   TfrmSettings = class(TForm)
> //...
>     sbDetectors: TScrollBox;
>     XStart, YStart: Single;
>     bMouseDrawing: Boolean;
>     FMouseBrush: TBrush;
> //...
>   public
>     { Public declarations }
>   end;
>
> var
>   frmSettings: TfrmSettings;
>
> implementation
>
> {$R *.fmx}
> procedure TfrmSettings.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
> begin
>   FMouseBrush := TBrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid, $FFD1DDA1); // $FF505050 { .$FFD1DDA1 } );
> end;
>
> procedure TfrmSettings.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
> begin
>   FMouseBrush.Free;
> end;
>
> procedure TfrmSettings.sbDetectorsMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
>   X, Y: Single);
> begin
>   XStart := X;
>   YStart := Y;
>   bMouseDrawing := True;
>   sbDetectors.Canvas.Fill.Assign(FMouseBrush);
> end;
>
> procedure TfrmSettings.sbDetectorsMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
> begin
>   if bMouseDrawing then
>   begin
>     sbDetectors.Canvas.BeginScene;
>     sbDetectors.Canvas.DrawRect(rectF(X, Y, XStart, YStart), 0, 0, [], 1);
>     sbDetectors.Canvas.EndScene;
>   end;
> end;
>
> procedure TfrmSettings.sbDetectorsMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
>   X, Y: Single);
> begin
>   bMouseDrawing := False;
> end;
> ```

This code doesn't work properly cause

1. I didn't find a way to clear the previously drawn rectangle (likecan be done in VCL: Pen.Mode := pmNotXor).
2. I could not find a simple way to translate X, Y coordinates to the control's (sbDetectors) Canvas coordinates (like in VCL: ClientToScreen).
       sbDetectors lays not on the form itself but on the stack of other
       controls.

How to do it?

Comment: Use the [TSelection](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Objects.TSelection) control.

Comment: You shouldn't paint in OnMouseMove. Instead invalidate, and paint in OnPaint. Invalidate again to clear the rectangle when you want it to go away. (Note in both cases, don't invalidate the entire screen, invalidate the sub-rect so you only repaint the smallest amount possible.) But even this is an unnecessarily large lot of work - try using a plain TRectangle component.

Comment: @peterv: That's a good class not known to me before, it will be useful, thanks. Though I need to do more complicated things by mouse than just a selection rectangle.

Comment: @Molochnik, you can always inherit from `TSelection` and expand it to whatever you want.

Comment: @David, so everything you draw should be placed under Onpaint event an and be invalidated outside, right? Very nice, but what to use to draw a simple framed rectangle with transparent background: DrawPath, DrawRectangle or FillReactangle or else?

Comment: @PeterV, yes i know but I am a little reluctant to override standard visual objects. Some time ago I tried to override standard listview and dbgrid components to add a small feature and in both cases I'll get some subtle program errors in various places, debugger started to behave strangely and then I decided not to override VCL objects without extreme need. Looks like I am not enough qualified for that.

Comment: @Molochnik Yes, paint in OnPaint; invalidate to cause a paint. I would use FillRect to fill with a transparent blue color. I can't remember if FillRect draws the edge using the stroke brush or not, but if not I'd then use DrawRect to add a solid edge to the rectangle.